# Apply two transformations on one axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have found `coord_trans`, but I'd like to apply `log10` and
`reverse` to my x-axis. I tried applying two transformation

```
ggplot(table) + aes(color=Vowel, x=F1, y=F2) + geom_point() + coord_trans(x="log10", y="log10") + coord_trans(x="reverse", y="reverse")
```

but only the first one was applied. So I tried linking them

```
ggplot(table) + aes(color=Vowel, x=F2, y=F1) + geom_point() + coord_trans(x=c("log10", "reverse"), y=c("log10", "reverse"))
```

Which gives me a plain error.

```
'c("log10_trans", "reverse_trans")' is not a function, character or symbol
```

How do I chain them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define new transformations using `trans_new`.

```
library(scales)
log10_rev_trans <- trans_new(
  "log10_rev",
  function(x) log10(rev(x)),
  function(x) rev(10 ^ (x)),
  log_breaks(10),
  domain = c(1e-100, Inf)
)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
   geom_point()   

p + coord_trans(y = log10_rev_trans)
```

Comment: The coordinates are reversed, but the labels are not.

Comment: Which labels?  Changing the order of the points won't change the axis labels.  Did you have some other code to label indiviual points?

Comment: Oh, totally forgot about that. I actually wanted to inverse the axis, not the points.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy way is to apply one of the transformations directly to the data and use the other with the plot function.

e.g.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(log10(Sepal.Length), log10(Sepal.Width), colour = Species)) + 
geom_point() + coord_trans(x="reverse", y="reverse")
```

Note: the reverse transformation does not work with the iris data but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I wandered in here looking for a 'composition of scales' function. I think one might be able to write such a thing as follows:

```
# compose transforms a and b, applying b first, then a:
`%::%`  <- function(atrans,btrans) {
  mytran <- scales::trans_new(name      = paste(btrans$name,'then',atrans$name),
                              transform = function(x) { atrans$transform(btrans$transform(x)) },
                              inverse   = function(y) { btrans$inverse(atrans$inverse(y)) },
                              domain    = btrans$domain,  # this could use improvement...
                              breaks    = btrans$breaks,  # not clear how this should work, tbh
                              format    = btrans$format)

}

ph <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans=scales::reverse_trans() %::% scales::log10_trans())
print(ph)
```

Comment: This probably _should_ compose `breaks`, `format` and `domain` together. The `domain` should probably be the intersection of the `btrans` domain and the b inverse of the `atrans` domain, and so on...